# Unable to Connect Azure Web PubSub Service with Postman WebSocket

Tags: azure, websocket, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-pubsub

I have generated Client Access URL using Client URL Generator with all access, which is working fine in Quickstart website provided by azure,
But if i try the same link in postman websocket gets connected
then if i send

{
"type": "joinGroup",
"group": "Group1",
"ackId": 1
}

to join group
Websocket gets disconnected.

Comment: Postman can connect web pages with HTTP/HTTPS not to the web WebSocket directly as far as I know. have to try this with this [URL](https://i.imgur.com/hX0jFfO.png) in postman . we can use the Azure function to connect to the web socket. Reference for Azure function connected with the [webPubsub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/tutorial-serverless-notification?tabs=javascript).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment postman has websocket feature recently introduced, i have also tried with other 3rd party websocket connection services, the url in the screen shot will do the back end work for sending specific json format. since i am trying to build an application and integrate azure pubsub, i would like to know the exact backend format to join group and send messages. which i am not able to test.

Comment: could you share the Postman WebSocket feature-related doc, the backend c#, or Python?

Comment: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/websocket/websocket/#:~:text=You%20can%20create%20a%20WebSocket%20request%20from%20the%20sidebar%20in,N%20or%20Ctrl%2BN.)

I have tried in below website too 
https://websocketking.com/

Comment: since it is still in beta it has bugs. I tested sending messages as well it disconnected. hope we should wait for wait new standard version role out. if you need any of the backend c#, or Python or let me know

Answer (score 0):

> Issues while connecting to the Azure Web PubSub service using Postman WebSocket.

- Check the version of Postman you are using supports WebSocket connections. WebSocket support was added in `Postman version 7.2.0`, are `compatible`.

Check the URL that you are using the correct `WebSocket URL` format for Azure Web PubSub. The URL should start with "wss://" and include the endpoint and hub details.

[image]

Azure Web PubSub requires [specific headers or authentication tokens](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-web-pubsub/includes/reference-json-requests.md) for successful WebSocket connections.

- Check if there are any firewall / network restrictions that preventing the WebSocket connection.

By default, Postman validates SSL certificates. If you are using a self-signed or custom certificate for  `Azure Web PubSub service` , you need to disable SSL certificate verification in Postman's settings.

- To enable the WebSocket protocol explicitly in Postman. To do this, go to Postman Settings, navigate to the "General" tab, and toggle the "Enable WebSocket" option.

[image]

Check the error messages when the WebSocket connection is closed or fails to establish.
Azure Web PubSub provides error messages or status codes.

[image]

For more information refer to the [Blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/build-serveless-real-time-chat-application-with-web-pubsub-and/ba-p/2433211) and [MSDoc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/how-to-postman-websocket)